# Terraform | 0.12.2 | Upgrade issues

Tags: terraform

I am getting below error while executing `terraform init` command after upgrading to `0.12.2` version. Earlier same code was working fine without issues in terraform `0.11.10` version.

alb.tf

```
tags {
    Name             = "${var.name}"
    Environment      = "${lookup(var.environment, terraform.workspace)}"
  }
```

lc.tf:-

```
  vars {
EFS_ENDPOINT = "${aws_efs_file_system.jenkins.dns_name}"
```

}

remote_state.tf line 4

```
config {
    bucket      =   "s3-terraform-state"
    key         =   "env:/${lookup(var.environment, terraform.workspace)}/cicd-security-groups/terraform.tfstate"
    region      =   "${var.region}"
  }
```

remote_state.tf line 14

```
config {
    bucket      =   "ttgsl-s3-terraform-state"
    key         =   "env:/${lookup(var.environment, terraform.workspace)}/cicd-kms-ebs/terraform.tfstate"
    region      =   "${var.region}"
  }
```

terraform validate -no-color

```
Error: Unsupported block type

  on alb.tf line 40, in resource "aws_lb_target_group" "jenkins_master":
  40:   tags {

Blocks of type "tags" are not expected here. Did you mean to define argument
"tags"? If so, use the equals sign to assign it a value.


Error: Unsupported block type

  on lc.tf line 4, in data "template_file" "jenkins_user_data_template":
   4:   vars {

Blocks of type "vars" are not expected here. Did you mean to define argument
"vars"? If so, use the equals sign to assign it a value.


Error: Unsupported block type

  on remote_state.tf line 4, in data "terraform_remote_state" "remote-cicd-security-groups_state":
   4:   config {

Blocks of type "config" are not expected here. Did you mean to define argument
"config"? If so, use the equals sign to assign it a value.


Error: Unsupported block type

  on remote_state.tf line 14, in data "terraform_remote_state" "remote-cicd-kms-ebs_state":
  14:   config {

Blocks of type "config" are not expected here. Did you mean to define argument
"config"? If so, use the equals sign to assign it a value.

make: *** [validate] Error 1
```

Comment: Is that happening on the `init` rather than the `plan` or `apply` commands?

Comment: It would also help if you could share a [mcve] so people can replicate this themselves.

Comment: There is a simple typo here: a random `}` in `aws_lb_target_group_jenkins_master_arn}`. If that was working in 0.11.x then that was a bug in 0.11.x.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Thank you.. After removing extra `}` I got new errors. Updating the error log

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
tags = {
    Name             = "${var.name}"
    Environment      = "${lookup(var.environment, terraform.workspace)}"
  }

vars = {
    EFS_ENDPOINT = "${aws_efs_file_system.jenkins.dns_name}"
}
```

We need to add `=` after tags, vars as well for config to avoid the errors.